# "We have to be hard on you, you have to be cured"

Tags: infinitives, comma-splices

"We have to be hard on you, you have to be cured," is grammatically correct?

Shouldn't it be "We have to be hard on you; you have to be cured," as these are two independent clauses. I've seen it in an Anthony Burgess novel.

Comment: Grammar and punctuation are unrelated insofar as the spoken version is grammatically correct without need of punctuation.

Comment: Anthony Burgess can punctuate however he wants.

Comment: Semicolon usage is up to you to define its (the semicolon's) purpose. It's simply a way for you to not start a new sentence when you don't want to. The is no such thing as "misuse of semicolons". It's a free world; use it the way you see fit.

Comment: I agree with you - it would be better with a semicolon. Personally, the comma looks out of place in the sentence and, had I written it, I would have used a dash instead. In most cases you will find that punctuation is influenced by the author's preferences and/or their publisher's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is still taking up space in the Unanswered Questions queue almost two months after being posted, let me offer a brief discussion of comma splices from a copy editor's perspective, in hopes of attracting an upvote and removing the question from Unanswered Questions.

The designation "comma splice" is founded on the supposed inadequacy of a comma as a link between two phrases that (1) would work if run as independent sentences, and (2) don't include a conjunction to help manage the shift from the first phrase to the second. In other words, as various commenters have observed, it's founded on an issue of punctuation, not one of grammar. Even so, in making decisions about punctuation, writers would do well to consider the effect that those choices may have on readers. If we were to punctuate the sentence as

> We have to be hard on you; you have to be cured.

I doubt that any reader would regard the sentence as wrongly punctuated. Some readers might prefer to see the two phrases broken into two separate sentences, and a few might prefer to see the phrases separated only by a comma. But the vast majority of readers, I suspect, wouldn't find the version with the semicolon sufficiently distracting to stop them in their tracks and break the momentum of their reading. The same cannot be said of comma splices, which are unusual enough and gratuitous enough to bother a not insignificant number of readers. And that, from a copyediting perspective, is reason enough to use a semicolon (or a period) and not a comma here.

Authors have the unalienable right to use punctuation as they see fit, including the right to use it in ways that call attention to particular punctuation decisions by opting against the more conventional choice(s) that most other writers use. But calling attention to unorthodox punctuation in this way can be problematic because it momentarily directs readers' attention away from the content of the text and toward the odd punctuation mark.

For some authors—perhaps most famously Louis-Ferdinand Céline with his thousands of ellipsis points—that may be a desirable effect. But for others it is self-defeating because it introduce a needless impediment to straightforward, nondistracted reading. If you're the author (and you aren't answerable to a publishing house), you get to choose. But if you're a reader and you really don't like comma splices, you get to choose, too—to abandon the piece and to avoid that author in future.

If you see using comma splices as a matter of principle in the struggle for unfettered self-expression, then by all means use them. Maybe doing so will prompt readers to complain to you, and you can inform them that the notion of comma splices as grammatical errors is based on ignorance of the difference between grammar and punctuation. To me, though, inviting avoidable disputes over trivial matters doesn't make much sense, assuming that you want your readers to give most of their attention to the ideas you're writing about and not to the punctuation you're using.

Comment: Its possible,, to "use" punctu!ation -- in way's that are# manifestly in-correc't. (All the same, please don't correct that sentence.)

Answer (score 0):

My English professor taught me a semicolon is used where a sentence does end; but does not. He also was very adamant regarding the necessity of a period where possible:

> We have to be hard on you. You have to be cured,

The semicolon is often misused. In most cases a new sentence is the better option.

Comment: Listen to tchrist, Hot Licks *and* Blessed Geek, your English professor is out of date.  See what I did there?

Comment: However, a few years ago I spent a lot of time proof-reading my wife's degree essays, and I corrected all similar occurrences [main clauses joined by just a comma], on the grounds that that the professors reading them would agree with Motoko Kusanagi's professor.  Was I wrong to do that?